# Deeper darkness and dancing lights interaction

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

Hello I am relatively new to Pathfinder and I ran into an interaction that I don't quite know how it will resolve as a Drow with Darkvision.

As a Drow with the feats, [Drow Nobility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/arg-feats/drow-nobility-drow) and [Improved Drow Nobility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/arg-feats/improved-drow-nobility-drow). I can cast [Deeper Darkness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/deeper-darkness) and [Dancing Lights](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dancing-lights) twice a day. With Deeper Darkness I lower the light level by 2 steps out 60 feet, so Bright light becomes dim, normal becomes dark, while dim and dark become supernaturally dark.

Dancing lights on the other hand lets you create 4 magical light sources (Torches, spheres, or will-o'-wisps like orbs), or one faintly glowing humanoid shape. The reference I read says that a torch creates normal light out 20 feet and increases the light level by one another 20 feet out up to normal light level.

My question is what would happen if I cast Deeper Darkness on an object in dim light to create supernaturally dark and then I cast dancing lights. How would the dancing lights of the torches, will-o'-wisps orbs and the faintly glowing humanoid one interact with the deeper darkness environment.

If I understand correctly the torches will turn 20 feet of the deeper darkness to normal light and then another 20 feet will be darkness, but I am unsure how the orbs and the humanoid one will interact with deeper darkness. Thank you for your time and knowledge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dancing Lights will have no effect on the Deeper Darkness

Regardless of how much light the Dancing Lights give off, keep in mind this line of the Darkness entry:

> Magical light sources only increase the light level in an area if they are of a higher spell level than darkness.

Since Deeper Darkness is level 3, and Dancing Lights is level 0, the effect of the Dancing Lights spell doesn't work at all withing the effect of the Deeper Darkness spell.